# How to programmatically disable auto-select on <input type=text> elements?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Then the user uses TAB or SHIFT-TAB to "jump" to a certain text-box and that text-box happens to have a value in it, then that value will be auto-selected. I would like to disable this behavior.

I assume that can be done inside the focusin event handler:

```
$("input:text").focusin(function() {
    // "un-select" the value and place the text-cursor
    // at the beginning or end of the value
});
```

Comment: Why do you need to disable that behavior? I'm just curious.

Comment: @Juhana If I want to manipulate the value of the text-box, I need to use the RIGHT-ARROW key to "un-select" the value. Auto-select is optimized for scenarios where you need to replace the entire value with a new one.

Answer (score 3):

```
$(function() {
    $('input').bind('focus', function(e) {
       return false;
    });
});
```

Using jQuery 1.4.3+ you can use the shortcut version:

```
$(function() {
    $('input').bind('focus', false);
});
```

Example: http://www.jsfiddle.net/P8LDB/

Comment: @Sime Vidas, that's one thing I forget about with jQuery, that it's only able to abstract away *most* of the cross-browser differences. =/

Comment: Returning false in the focus event handler doesn't stop the selection of the entire value in the field when (shift-)tabbing into an input.

You can also try on your fiddle with non-jQuery code:

document.querySelectorAll('input').forEach(input => {input.addEventListener('focus', () => false)});